# Access violation on Server 2012R2 during UAC with custom credential provider

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com, credential-providers

I have a custom credential provider and the credential implements `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential`. It is written using Visual C++ 2019 and ATL. It works on Server 2016/2019 and Windows 10/11, if I use it on Server 2012R2, then the UI crashes during UAC--trying to elevate a non-admin user to use an Administrator PowerShell session for example.

I attached a remote debugger and the debugger intercepts the exception consistently as: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE9E627EC3 (authui.dll) in consent.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.`

I had some logging/debugging code and I could see that the system never calls my `Connect()` or `GetSerialization()` method on the credential when it crashes. My logging showed the username and password getting set, but then after keying the Enter key or clicking on OK, the process crashes without ever asking the credential to serialize its credentials. The logging showed that the last call into my credential provider was to `ICredentialProviderCredential::SetStringValue()` which was corresponding to entering the password before keying the Enter key.

Since it was throwing an access violation, I assumed that I must be passing bad data back to the system when it was calling the `ICredentialProvder::GetFieldDescriptorAt()` or possibly the `ICredentialProviderCredential::GetStringValue()` or some other `CredentialProvider::Get...()` function. I've gone over the methods with fine tooth comb as well as all other methods and have found nothing. For the GetStringValue() implementation, I am calling `SHStrDupW()` like in the SDK examples, and for `GetFieldDescriptorAt()` I am calling the same functions as the SDK examples. In fact, I copied the SDK code.

I decided to distill my credential provider down to a minimal reproducible example. That minimal example is at https://github.com/willcoxson/CredDemo

If anyone could see where I might be passing bad data back in one of the methods, I'd sure be grateful.

Comment: you not need return `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` in `CPUS_CREDUI`  Scenario (it only for `CPUS_LOGON`) crasj was just after system query you for `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` and you return it. this is windows bug, not your . it try access object (`CPLAPCallback::_pSingleton`)by  0 pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` have sense only for `CPUS_LOGON`case. so for other scenarion your `QueryInterface` must return `E_NOINTERFACE` when system ask for `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential`

in your concrete case we have `CPUS_CREDUI` scenario. inside function

`void CGetSerializationJob::Do(CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_THREAD_JOB_CONTEXT const &)` system query you for `IConnectableCredentialProviderCredential` (*"9387928b-ac75-4bf9-8ab2-2b93c4a55290"* )

[image]

and if you return this interface - run next code

[image]

system try access some object by pointer - **`CPLAPCallback::_pSingleton`**

but pointer is 0. crash exactly at yellow line ( *0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.* )

Comment: Thanks. Interesting...  I had copied an open source CP as the basis for our CP for doing 2FA with an external web API. That OSS CP used IConnectableCredentialProvider and no matter Windows 10/2016/2019/11, it had always worked and was always calling ::Connect(). Seems I will have to re-think my implementation maybe.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson this is bug in win 8.1 implementation how minimun, in CPUS_CREDUI case.